# foriegn keys missing in ruby on rails schema.rb file after running rake db:schema:dump

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, rake

I had a data model generation script which works fine by invoking mysql command line utility. I want RoR to use this data model that includes several foreign key dependencies within the tables. I found that $ rake db:schema:dump creates the db/schema.rb file and it did, but it is missing all the foreign key constraints/clauses. This is obviously a problem.

I've watched the RoR tutorial on lynda.com and the foriegn key functionality is pretty basic and assumes a lot of conventions like there can only be one foreign key and it needs to have a naming convention of table1_table2_id or something.

I was chatting on IRC yesterday in the #rubyonrails channel and one person said that RoR ignores foriegn keys and the rake db:schema:dump seems to be doing so.

For example this is the mysql statement:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students` (
  `studentid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `teacherid` INT NOT NULL,
  `parentid` INT NULL,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dob` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `isadult` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cellphone` INT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `addr_streetno` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `addr_aptno` INT NULL,
  `addr_city` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `addr_state` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `addr_zip` INT NULL,
  `photo` MEDIUMBLOB NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`studentid`),
  INDEX `parentid_idx` (`parentid` ASC),
  INDEX `teacherid_idx` (`teacherid` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `parentid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parentid`)
    REFERENCES `parents` (`parentid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `teacherid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`teacherid`)
    REFERENCES `teachers` (`teacherid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

In the schema.rb, it shows up as this and doesn't have any directives for foreign keys. what gives:

```
create_table "students", primary_key: "studentid", force: true do |t|
   t.integer  "teacherid",                      null: false
   t.integer  "parentid"
   t.string   "firstname",     limit: 45,       null: false
   t.string   "lastname",      limit: 45,       null: false
   t.datetime "dob",                            null: false
   t.boolean  "isadult",                        null: false
   t.string   "email",         limit: 45,       null: false
   t.integer  "cellphone"
   t.string   "username",      limit: 45,       null: false
   t.string   "password",      limit: 45,       null: false
   t.string   "addr_streetno", limit: 45
   t.integer  "addr_aptno"
   t.string   "addr_city",     limit: 45
   t.string   "addr_state",    limit: 45
   t.integer  "addr_zip"
   t.binary   "photo",         limit: 16777215
end

add_index "students", ["parentid"], name: "parentid_idx", using: :btree
add_index "students", ["teacherid"], name: "teacherid_idx", using: :btree
```

Comment: I recommend you include your `schema.rb` file, as well as your `tables` or `models` or any other relevant code

Comment: I would have to go through significant scrubbing to do so. The key idea of the question seems clear enough, no?

Comment: and you are wondering why the `schema` doesn't show the `foreign keys`?

Comment: @WaliAli yes. Thats one question.

Comment: see my answer. let me know how much I understood your question.

Answer (score -2):

in Rails, where to place the `foreign key` is determined by the association of your models.

Let's say you have the following two models:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

the foreign key will be placed in the table declaring the `belongs_to` association. in this case, the `children` table.

the foreign key is the name of the `parent model` with the suffix `_id`. in this case, it would be `parent_id`.

In Rails, this is how you add `parent_id` to the `children_table`:

```
rails g migration AddParentIdToChild parent_id:integer
```

then run `rake db:migrate`. afterwards, the foreign key should show up in your `schema`

I hope I didn't misunderstood your question.
For more info about foreign keys and tables, see the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Yes this was helpful. I have parentid and teacherid as the foreign key columns in the students table. (Each student must have a teacher and may have a parent). So Im thinking that I must rename the foreign key columns as parent_id and teacher_id. Also, in the teachers and parents table, I would have to rename the primary key as "id", right. Tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: The primary keys are automatically created for you by rails. you don't have to add them. yes, if you haven't yet, add the foreign keys: `parent_id and teacher_id` to student table. if you go to `rails console` and do `Student`, you'll see the `students table` has a `primary key`

Comment: See my situation is that I have to work backwards into the rails data modelling convention from an existing data model script that I had written when I was beginning to design the backend of the application in question. I didnt know about the primary key and foriegn key naming conventions then. Now I have to adapt the model to suit to rails ways.

Comment: Just saying I think I know what to do. Will holler back if I come across any other roadblocks on this thread.

Comment: cool. at least you don't have to worry about `primary keys`. They are given to you. I always use the `console` to see what `attributes`, including `foreign_keys`, my table has.